# 'Strong' presence, but ________ absence?

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests

What would be a good collocation **to emphasize the absence** of something. A 'strong absence' sounds a bit oxymoronic to me.

Comment: The most common construction is a "***conspicuous absence***".

Comment: Thank you!! I also thought of 'striking', but your choice of word is ten times better.

Comment: Sure, no problem; but fair warning, the phrase is a bit hackneyed.

Comment: much less conspicuous, but not completely absent is:  ***distinct absence***

Comment: +1 for *conspicuous*. Also: a *complete absence*.

Answer (score 1):

gaping absence

also "gaping void" left by his/her absence ...

Comment: Welcome to [ELU.SE] @Youstay. Your post would be improved if it included a reference.